# Disable calling method when return to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have multiple spinner on one fragment. When I change value of one , I need change adapter values of another.(For example if in first spinner I select `users` in second I need get `first name`,`last name` etc.. if in first I select topic ,I need to get `topic 1`,`topic 2` etc. I have method `setSpinner()` witch set second spinner by value of first,and this work. But problem is when i go on next fragment and back to first fragment `setSpinner` is called again and reset second spinner.

Part of my code is:

```
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor edt;
Integer PTypeInt,PKindInt;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.finesvehicleinformation, container, false);

    pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);  // I use shared preferences to know are value of spinner changed
    edt = pref.edit();
    PTypeInt = pref.getInt("PType_spinner", -1);
    PType_spinner  = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spPType);
    // i wold not write set of adapter etc because this all work
    PType_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
             if (PTypeInt == -1) {    //Here something is not right because PTypeInt is always -1
                 setSpinner(2, separated[0], "", "", v);
             }               
         }
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
         }
    });
 return v;
}

public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
   PKindInt=-1;  // set on -1 that I can select new value from spinner when I need        
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
    edt.putInt("PType_spinner", PType_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).commit();
    edt.putInt("PKind_spinner", PKind_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).commit();
}
```

When i use on first frame all is ok,when i go to next,and again on first i get value for PkindInt , but when i check it in `PKind_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener` is always `-1`.

I need call `setSpinner` when i manually select value from spinner, but not when i call fragment again. Fragment is in FrameLayout. i call it with

```
        currentFragment = myfragment[fNo];//fNo is number of fragment

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, currentFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Please help.

Comment: PTypeInt is set from sharedpreferences inside onCreateView and shared preferences value for it is reset inside onPause. When you come back to your first fragment, does your onCreateView gets called again? Just wanted to ensure PTypeInt repicks its value from shared preferences

Comment: @random, Yes it is called again,and on start i get value for PTypeInt,i write it out in toast message and it is ok. Later idk , like that program first reset it on -1 and than call PType_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener.

Comment: why are you setting PKindInt=-1 inside onViewCreated?

Comment: Also I think you should make use of this article http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html to pass a value to another fragment instead of saving it in shared preferences

Comment: I try  on end of `onCreateView` but i have same problem ,than i try " onViewCreated" because i was think that ` onViewCreated` called after  `onCreateView`. I need to set it on -1 that user later can use setSpinner(). I wold try now with this.Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created test project with two spinners where the second spinner depends on the first spinner, and the button which replaces this fragment with other, where you can see selection of your spinners. Second Fragment has back button - when it pressed user returns to the first fragment with previous selection kept. Also when application launched again selection also restored to previous selection.

[full project zipped sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5KouoPaI5qqMGZlZ0NkeWQ4T1U/view?usp=sharing)

Main selection and state save/restoration is below:

```
package me.shikhov.testmultispinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "test-spinner";

    private Spinner spinner1;
    private Spinner spinner2;

    private int spinner1Selection;
    private int spinner2Selection;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        SharedPreferences sp = activity.getSharedPreferences("default", 0);

        spinner1Selection = sp.getInt("spinner1", AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION);
        spinner2Selection = sp.getInt("spinner2", AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION);

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "spinner1 => " + spinner1Selection);
            Log.i(TAG, "spinner2 => " + spinner2Selection);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        ArrayAdapter spinner1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            new String[]{"item1", "item2", "item3"});

        spinner1.setAdapter(spinner1Adapter);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        boolean firstSelection = true;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onItemSelected " + position + " firstSelection " + firstSelection);
            }

            String selected = ((String) spinner1.getSelectedItem());

            spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    new String[]{
                             selected + " subItem1",
                             selected + " subitem2",
                             selected + " subitem3"}));

            if (firstSelection) {
                spinner2.setSelection(spinner2Selection);
                firstSelection = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
            spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[0]));
        }
    });


        view.findViewById(R.id.next_fragment).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragments_root, new NextFragment()).commit();
        }
    });

    spinner1.setSelection(spinner1Selection);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "spinner2 onItemSelected " + position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("default", 0);

    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {

        Log.i(TAG, "spinner1 := " + spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition());
        Log.i(TAG, "spinner2 := " + spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition());
    }

    sp.edit().putInt("spinner1", spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition())
            .putInt("spinner2", spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition())
            .commit();
    }
}
```